# Unable to retrieve information from mongoDB using redux

Tags: mongodb, redux, mern

I have designed a CRM tool using mern stack, when I tried to retrieve information specific information related to Project stages from mongoDB I was shown the error below:

```
getStages api error: 
TypeError: action.payload is not iterable
    at stageReducer (stageReducers.js:11)
    at combination (redux.js:528)
    at computeNextEntry (<anonymous>:3395:21)
    at recomputeStates (<anonymous>:3429:17)
    at <anonymous>:3809:22
    at Object.dispatch (redux.js:288)
    at dispatch (<anonymous>:3856:17)
    at index.js:11
    at dispatch (redux.js:659)
    at stageAction.js:7
```

Also, I have used redux for this implementation. I implemented the backend of this function and tested it with postman and it worked perfectly
but the frontend is not retrieving the information as expected. The stageReducer, stageAction and index.js files are given below:

stageReducer:

```
import { GET_STAGES } from "../constants/stageConstants";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    stages: []
};

const stageReducer = (state=INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case GET_STAGES:
            return{
                stages: [...action.payload]
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default stageReducer;
```

stageAction:

```
import { GET_STAGES } from "../constants/stageConstants";
import axios from "axios";

export const getStages = () => async dispatch =>{
    try{
        const response = await axios.get('/stages');
        dispatch({
            type: GET_STAGES,
            payload: response.data.stages
        });
        console.log(response);
    }catch(err){
        console.log('getStages api error:', err);
    }
}
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./components/App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/store';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store ={store}>
      <App/>
    </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: check the value of `response.data.stages` seems like it is not an array.

Comment: @NikitaMazur will u pls let me know on how I should change it. pls?

Comment: depends on what you get in `response.data`